# MS Excel if statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This may be really easy for someone who used excel allot in the past but i just can't get the right formula.

I have a large spreadsheet which i need to add a mark up onto but the mark up which adds on is dependent on variables. Unfortunately this result has to go on the end of a already big formula, the ######## represents where the IF statement will be placed.

```
IF >55 and is square = 15
IF >55 and is not square = 15
IF <55 and is Square = 25
IF <55 and is not square = 30
```

Cell D2 = has the numerical value
Cell G2 = Has the shapes in it.

`=(((100-V2)/100)*U2*D2)+((((100-V2)/100)*U2*D2)/100*##########)`

Comment: Do you use "allot" a lot? As for your question, I'd be inclined to use extra cells for intermediate results.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, grammar and spelling are not my strongest points. So for example instead of adding the big if statement at the end of the formula. have it so it looks up a set of cells which will have the value in from separate if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really recommend you break the formula into cells, but if it's needed to be in one single cell, the formula can be done as well...

`IF(D2>55;IF(G2="square";15;15);IF(G2="square";25;30))`

So it's gonna be like:

```
=(((100-V2)/100)*U2*D2)+((((100-V2)/100)*U2*D2)/100*IF(D2>55;IF(G2="square";15;15);IF(G2="square";25;30)))
```

Comment: This work's like a gem, where once all the Price has been generated a macro runs and removes the formula's after. would it still be better practice to use a broken version into cells?

Comment: I don't like to use nested IF in Excel and big formulas.
You could create a cell that represents ((100-V2)/100)*U2*D2 and a cell that represents the markup (IFs)
Assuming these cells are gonna be Z2 and AA2, for example...
You can generate the formula =(1+(AA2/100))*Z2

Answer (score 1):

A little shorter (addresses D2=55):

```
=15+15*(D2<55)-5*(D2<55)*(G2="Square")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big fan of the nested `if`s in Excel, especially when they contain and/or conditions.  The typical formula would look something like:

```
=if(and(c1,c2),x1,if(and(c3,c4),x2,...
```

YUCK!

I'm definitely a VBA minimalist, but this does appear to be a good application of it.  Make a custom function like:

```
Function FooBoo(Val As Integer, Shape As String) As Integer

  Dim result As Integer

  If Val > 55 And Shape = "square" Then
    result = 15
  ElseIf Val > 55 Then
    result = 15
  ElseIf Val < 55 And Shape = "square" Then
    result = 25
  ElseIf Val < 55 Then
    result = 30
  End If

  FooBoo = result

End Function
```

And then you can call it from within Excel:

```
=(((100-V2)/100)*U2*D2)+((((100-V2)/100)*U2*D2)/100*FooBoo(val,shape))
```

If it's part of the workbook itself, it's no less portable than any other Excel formula, and it's more transparent and easier to maintain.

Also, unrelated, but I did note some things in your logic:

1. 15 seems to be the result for values > 55, whether or not it's a square.  You really could limit your first condition to values > 55
2. You haven't defined what happens if the value is exactly 55.  Was one of those conditions >= or <=?

Comment: Complete mind slip, if the value is 55 it should be considered the same as great than so >=. once all the information is complete, all formula's are removed and a CSV is saved and uploaded to a ecommerce site.